# Create esp32 static library based on multiple components

Tags: components, static-libraries, esp32, esp-idf

I'm new to *esp-idf* developement and I want to build a **static library** for *esp32*.
I've read the espressif documentation (available here : [Programming Guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#example-project)) but I can't manage to create a proper **.a** file.

The idea is to develop a new library of wrapper and functions which include functions from [esp-dsp](https://github.com/espressif/esp-dsp) library. I've add the esp-dsp component to my project and created my own component: `my_component`.

There is my project structure right now:

```
- first_project/
             - CMakeLists.txt
             - sdkconfig
             - components/ - esp-dsp/ - CMakeLists.txt
                                      - ...
                                      - ...
                           - my_component/ - CMakeLists.txt
                                           - my_component.c
                                           - include/ 
                                                     - my_component.h
             - main/       - CMakeLists.txt
                           - main.c

             - build/
```

Following are the `CMakeLists.txt` files:

**CMakeLists.txt (first_project)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(first_test)
```

**CMakeLists.txt (main)**

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "main.c"
                    INCLUDE_DIRS "."
                    REQUIRES my_component esp-dsp)
```

**CMakeLists.txt (my_component)**

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "my_component.c"
                    INCLUDE_DIRS "include"
                    REQUIRES esp-dsp)
```

In `my_component.c` there are functions from `esp-dsp`

With the previous files, I managed to create a binary to flash into ESP32 board but the next step is to build a static library (my_library.a) where there are functions inside `my_component.c`.

So I tried to modify `CmakeLists.txt (main)` in order to create the static library [MyStaticLib.a] regarding the component `my_component`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(first_test)

ADD_LIBRARY( MyStaticLib STATIC
             components/my_component/my_component.c )
SET( APP_EXE StaticTest )
ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${APP_EXE}
                main/main.c ) 

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${APP_EXE}
                    MyStaticLib )
```

However, during the build, I can't see the `include` path folder of `my_component`. Then the compilation failed because of `my_component.h:No such file or directory`

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/MyStaticLib.dir/components/my_component/my_component.c.obj 
ccache C:\Users\julien\.espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2020r3-8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe   -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/MyStaticLib.dir/components/my_component/my_component.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\MyStaticLib.dir\components\my_component\my_component.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/MyStaticLib.dir/components/my_component/my_component.c.obj   -c ../components/my_component/my_component.c
../components/my_component/my_component.c:2:10: fatal error: my_component.h: No such file or directory
```

The problem is only present when I modify the CMakeLists.txt from main to build the static library.

I though the variable **INCLUDE_DIRS** from `CMakeLists.txt` file could solved the problem but in vain.

Any idea where I'm doing wrong in CMakeLists.txt parameter in order to build **.a** static library to be used as a component in other project?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build the example with your component added as you do.
You will see all the components got build as a library(`.a`) under `build/esp-idf/` folder.

Use that `libmy_component.a` in other projects along with `libesp_dsp.a`.

Comment: The build works as exepected and I could generate the `libmy_component.a`.
However, when I want to add it to a new project,,the compilation doesn't work as expected. I added `esp-dsp` as a component and my static library with the commands (`add_library`, `set property` and `target_link_libraries`).
There are errors of reference from `esp-dsp`:  

`../main/../lib/my_libray/libmy_component.a(my_component.c.obj):(.literal.process_and_show2+0x0): undefined reference to dsps_fft_w_table_fc32`

Comment: I linked both `libmy_component.a` AND `libesp_dsp.a` to my project and **it works well now**. I though I could add only the `libmycomponent.a` as a static library and `esp-dsp` as a component but it didn't work as expected.